# Why is data usage very high in the Instagram app?

Tags: applications

Just by opening your instagram app you will be faced with a high volume of internet usage

Why is data usage very high in the Instagram app?

Answer (score 0):

Because on Instagram is a lot of pictures and videos and that uses quite a lot of data. I don't use Instagram a lot but it used about 7GB of data in less then a month (on wifi). However there is "cellular data use" in instagram settings and you have option to set it to use less data, however I don't know how efficient is that.